# How to create a query using Access from a given SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-office, sql-view

Someone gave me the following SQL and wants me to do a query using Access, so that it returns the information that they need. All dbo_**** are databases where they get the information from.

I tried to do the following SQL using a design view, but its not working, the datasheet(table) doesnt match the information.

I get lost in the lines LEFT OUTER JOIN ... I dont know what to do with anything after that. Can someone help me, please ?
Or if someone someone can edit the SQL so that it works on Access just copying in the SQL view mode.

Thank you.

```
Declare @data datetime
set @data = '2013-12-31'

--Fundos
SELECT 
       RelCliSFN.CdCrt, 
       MC5.Nome 'NomeCarteira',
       MC5.CGC 'CNPJCarteira',       
       player_adm.NomeCurto 'Administrador',
       RelCliSFN.Cliente, 
       CE5.Nome 'NomeCliente',
       CE5.CPFCGC 'CPF/CNPJCliente',
       VigRelCliSFN.DtIni, 
       VigRelCliSFN.DtFim
 FROM 
 RelCliSFN
 Inner JOIN MC5 ON MC5.Carteira = RelCliSFN.CdCrt
 INNER JOIN MC5Auxiliar ON MC5.Carteira = MC5Auxiliar.Carteira
 Inner Join VigRelCliSFN ON RelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN = VigRelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN
 Inner Join CE5 ON CE5.Cliente=RelCliSFN.Cliente 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayAdmxMC5 ON MC5.Carteira = PlayAdmxMC5.CdCrt AND     PlayAdmxMC5.DtIniVig =
(SELECT     MAX(DtIniVig) FROM          PlayAdmxMC5 WHERE      MC5.Carteira = CdCrt AND DtIniVig < MC5.DataAtual) 
 INNER JOIN Player player_adm ON PlayAdmxMC5.IdPlayAdm = player_adm.ID 
WHERE
--MC5Auxiliar.bNaoExpCCSFN is null
((VigRelCliSFN.DtIni <= @data)
and ((VigRelCliSFN.DtFim >= @data) or (VigRelCliSFN.DtFim is null)))
and MC5.CGC <> 0
and CE5.Assessor not in (17, 99)
and CE5.CPFCGC <>0
and MC5.TipoCarteira <> 4
--and RelCliSFN.CdCrt = 3`
```

Comment: We know that Access can connect to a SQL Server using linked tables or other methods.  Have you done that first?  Can you then run a very simple SELECT to see if that works  first?

Comment: I agree with @Leptonator, this looks like a pass through query which is being executed on SQL Server. The reason I think that is the `Declare @data datetime` syntax is not Access SQL but is SQL Server sql.

Comment: i'm kind of lost in your joins. `(SELECT     MAX(DtIniVig) FROM          PlayAdmxMC5 WHERE      MC5.Carteira = CdCrt AND DtIniVig < MC5.DataAtual)`no idea where it belongs to

Comment: one of the key parts of the explanation from above about it being a pass through query from SQL Server is that when you put the SQL statement in you need to change the query type from select statement to "pass through" if you are using 2007 or later this is done in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already mentioned, your query has MS SQL-Server syntax. So there are three ways you could solve your problem.

**Solution 1:**
Create a view in the SQL-Server database.

To do this, open your SQL-Server Management Studio. Go to *YourServer* > databases > *YourDatabase* > views. Right click on "views" and then select "new view...". Close the "add table" window. Copy your sql-code into the sql window (the one saying "SELECT FROM"). You will get an error message saying that your code can't be displayed. Ignore it. Save your view. You can connect it to your Access database the same way you would connect a table.

**Solution 2:**
Use a SQL-Passthrough query in Access.

This is a bit complicated to explain, because almost every Access version has a slightly different menu. I'll explain it for Access 2007.

Create a new query. Close the "add table" window. Choose "Pass-Through" from the design menu (I don't know exactly if the menu label of the english version is "design". In my version it says "Entwurf"). Open the properties window. Insert the correct ODBC string. The easiest way to get an ODBC-string is to use one from an existing ODBC-table. Go to the VBA immediate window (Ctrl + G) and write `?CurrentDb.TableDefs("YourTable").Connect` (instead of YourTable you have to insert the name of your ODBC-table). Press Return. You should get something like

```
ODBC;DSN=YourConnection;Description=IAmAnODBCConnection;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=YourDatabase
```

Copy this string into the ODBC property of your query. Be sure the option "returns records" is set to "Yes". Copy you SQL into the query and save it.

**Solution 3:**
Convert your SQL Server syntax to Access syntax. Before doing this, you have to connect every table which is used in the query. I can't test my syntax conversion, but this should work:

```
PARAMETERS data DateTime = #2013-12-31#;

SELECT 
       RelCliSFN.CdCrt, 
       MC5.Nome "NomeCarteira",
       MC5.CGC "CNPJCarteira",       
       player_adm.NomeCurto "Administrador",
       RelCliSFN.Cliente, 
       CE5.Nome "NomeCliente",
       CE5.CPFCGC "CPF/CNPJCliente",
       VigRelCliSFN.DtIni, 
       VigRelCliSFN.DtFim
 FROM 
 RelCliSFN
 Inner JOIN MC5 ON MC5.Carteira = RelCliSFN.CdCrt
 INNER JOIN MC5Auxiliar ON MC5.Carteira = MC5Auxiliar.Carteira
 Inner Join VigRelCliSFN ON RelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN = VigRelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN
 Inner Join CE5 ON CE5.Cliente=RelCliSFN.Cliente 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayAdmxMC5 ON MC5.Carteira = PlayAdmxMC5.CdCrt AND     PlayAdmxMC5.DtIniVig =
(SELECT     MAX(DtIniVig) FROM          PlayAdmxMC5 WHERE      MC5.Carteira = CdCrt AND DtIniVig < MC5.DataAtual) 
 INNER JOIN Player player_adm ON PlayAdmxMC5.IdPlayAdm = player_adm.ID 
WHERE
((VigRelCliSFN.DtIni <= [data])
and ((VigRelCliSFN.DtFim >= [data]) or (VigRelCliSFN.DtFim is null)))
and MC5.CGC <> 0
and CE5.Assessor not in (17, 99)
and CE5.CPFCGC <>0
and MC5.TipoCarteira <> 4
```

Well I don't know if Access can handle the equation of PlayAdmxMC5.DtIniVig = (Subquery). If it doesn't work, you should create a new query containing only the subquery and then connect it to this query.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, but I still couldnt get it to work! I am importing the Databases needed using ODBC and I am trying to change this syntax to a Access syntax as @Dorian suggested on solution 3. But as you said, Access cant handle the subquery equation. How would I connect a new query to the main one ?

When I do this LEFT OUTER JOIN PlayAdmxMC5 ON MC5.Carteira = PlayAdmxMC5.CdCrt , and then try to LEFT JOIN DtIniVig = (subquery) , it says that there are ambigous Joins.

I am going crazy with this Query already. haha

Comment: Also, when I do this main Query on Access and after doing the LEFT JOIN, it says to INNER JOIN another database, but when I do this, it also says the there are ambigous Joins. :/ 
I will post later the SQL Code that I have

Answer (score 0):

MAIN CODE I am using

```
   SELECT dbo_RelCliSFN.CdCrt, dbo_MC5.Nome AS NomeCarteira, dbo_MC5.CGC AS CNPJCarteira, dbo_RelCliSFN.Cliente, dbo_CE5.Nome AS NomeCliente, dbo_CE5.CPFCGC AS [CPF/CNPJCliente], dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtIni, dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtFim
FROM ((((dbo_RelCliSFN INNER JOIN dbo_CE5 ON dbo_RelCliSFN.Cliente = dbo_CE5.Cliente) INNER JOIN dbo_MC5 ON dbo_RelCliSFN.CdCrt = dbo_MC5.Carteira) INNER JOIN dbo_MC5Auxiliar ON dbo_MC5.Carteira = dbo_MC5Auxiliar.Carteira) INNER JOIN dbo_VigRelCliSFN ON dbo_RelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN = dbo_VigRelCliSFN.IdRelCliSFN) LEFT JOIN Query1 ON dbo_MC5.Carteira = Query1.CdCrt
GROUP BY dbo_RelCliSFN.CdCrt, dbo_MC5.Nome, dbo_MC5.CGC, dbo_RelCliSFN.Cliente, dbo_CE5.Nome, dbo_CE5.CPFCGC, dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtIni, dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtFim, dbo_MC5.TipoCarteira, dbo_CE5.Assessor
HAVING (((dbo_RelCliSFN.CdCrt)=802) AND ((dbo_MC5.CGC)<>0) AND ((dbo_CE5.CPFCGC)<>0) AND ((dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtIni)<=#12/31/2013#) AND ((dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtFim)>=#12/31/2013# Or (dbo_VigRelCliSFN.DtFim) Is Null) AND ((dbo_MC5.TipoCarteira)<>4) AND ((dbo_CE5.Assessor) Not In (17.19)));
```